On evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}$
This is part of a problem for determining whether $\\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}\\}$ is convergent or divergent. The ratio test is a separate portion, to be clear.
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}$$
I've only tried approximating it via substitutions, which gave me $0$. The extent of my studying so far is only until formally evaluating limits of exponential functions at infinity.
Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$(-10)^x$ does not make sense for irrational $x$. Are you considering $x$ to be a natural number? In that case the notation $n$ would be much less misleading.

@JulioPuerta I will publish an edit. Thanks

root test will help for absolute value.

$|\frac {(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}| = |\frac {(-10)^n}{16^n(n+1)}| = |(-\frac 58)^n(n+1)| <| (-\frac 58)^n|$  so the limit is clearly $0$.

$$\\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}\\}={\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{10}{16}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}}
$$
The limit at $\infty$ is of the form $\frac{0}{\infty}$ which cleary tends to $0$

$\\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}\\}={\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(10)^n}{4^{2n}(n+1)}}$
Using Alternating series test:

$|a_n|=(\frac{10}{16})^n\frac{1}{n+1}$ is decreasing since $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\frac{10}{16}\frac{n+1}{n+2}<1$

$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$, which you have proved.


Thus, this series is convergent.
